# ssh_exchange_identification after few attempts

Tags: ssh, openssh, gitlab

To help find diagnose a ssh issue with a gitlab server, I've written the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
while : ; do
    ssh -v git@example.com || exit 1
done
```

After few successful iterations (sometimes 3, something 10 and more), I get the following output:

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

What could cause this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you find odd about being notified the connection was closed by the remote host?

Comment: I want to know why after few attempts the server closes my connection instead of authenticate me successfully like all the previous attempts.

Comment: I would assume it has to do with the configuration of the server itself.  I took the message more as a confirmation your previous connections were closed by the server.

Comment: What kind of configuration should I look for on the server?

Comment: I would look for any configuration options that deals with how many connections a single client is allowed to keep open.  Are you able to duplicate the number of connections that are made until new connections replace old connections?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems to be some kind of rate limiting of the API as the problem is gone after some time and only occurs if you request a large number of Git operations (files). Unfortunately, there only seems to be a rate limit documented for the authentication part. So could you solve it somehow?